# Scalability Azure Function/AWS Lambda

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, scalability, azure-functions

I'm considering to use Azure Function/AWS Lambda/Serverless for backend. How does it scale to million of requests, that the code has to open database. I understand it does not reuse the connection?

For example the call is something like this.

```
using (var db = new Database(..,))
{
  // db calls
}
```

How does it scale out, and is it efficent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is somewhat imprecise. I don't know much about Azure, but for AWS Lambda it scales well. If you have 1 million concurrent requests Lambda would create an instance for each of those requests. Be aware that there is [a default limit](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/limits.html) of 1000 concurrent executions per region, but these can be increased with a support request.

After a first request has been made a container **may** be reused. There is a [blog post](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/container-reuse-in-lambda/) explaining how it works. While it's not recommended you can try buffer your connection within the container. Depending on database and driver your connection may stale during the freeze or it may still work. For one of the Lambdas I use buffering works quite well. You should be aware when you don't close the connection properly this may lead to **leaks** on your database server and of course you should **validate** the connection before using it again.

Using Java I put the connection into the scope of the class and check within my handler if the connection is already initialized e.g.:

```
public class LambdaHandler implements RequestStreamHandler {
  private Connection con = null;

  public void handleRequest(InputStream inputStream,
      OutputStream outputStream, Context context) {
    if (con == null) {
      con = getConnection(context);
    } else {
      con = validateConnection(context, con);
    }
  }
```

You can probably do the same using the language you use. I wouldn't be surprised if Azure Functions work quite similar to AWS Lambda, but you better check the documentation for verification.

Answer (score 2):

When it comes to using DB connection in lambda in AWS, you should read about [container execution model](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/lambda-introduction.html) of lambda. When a lambda is invoked, AWS spins up a container to run the code inside the handler function. So if you define the Database connection outside the handler function it will be shared among the invocations of Lambda functions. You can find that in the above link.

> Any declarations in your Lambda function code (outside the handler code, see Programming Model) remains initialized, providing additional optimization when the function is invoked again. For example, if your Lambda function establishes a database connection, instead of reestablishing the connection, the original connection is used in subsequent invocations. You can add logic in your code to check if a connection already exists before creating one.

```
const pg = require('pg');
const client = new pg.Client(<connection_string>);

exports.handler = (event, context, cb) => {  
  client.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE ', (err, users) => {
    // Do stuff with users
    cb(null); // Finish the function cleanly
});
};
```

Refer [this](http://blog.rowanudell.com/database-connections-in-lambda/) blog post.

But there is a caveat.

> When you write your Lambda function code, do not assume that AWS Lambda always reuses the container because AWS Lambda may choose not to reuse the container. Depending on various other factors, AWS Lambda may simply create a new container instead of reusing an existing container.

Additionally you can create a scheduled job to warm up lambda function. (runs in every 5mins)